# Remove line breaks at a specific character position in text file

Tags: regex, text-files

I'm working with a text file that was produced by a powershell script (not mine) that seems to have add a bunch of line breaks in the middle of actual line of output.

It looks something like this:

```
    line 1: text text text text te
    xt text text text text text te
    xt text
    line 2: text text text text te
    xt text text text text text te
    xt text
    etc...
```

When it should be like this:

```
    line 1: text text text text text text text text text text text text
    line 2: text text text text text text text text text text text text
    etc...
```

I'm thinking I should be able to use Notepad++ or something to do an advanced find and replace (maybe with RegEx?) and just remove the line breaks where the preceding number of characters was exactly 30 characters (or any arbitrary number).

Can anyone suggest a method to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: Give it a try then: https://regex101.com/r/656bWF/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is really separated by exactly 22 characters, you could try

```
(.{22})\n\s*
```

Which needs to be replaced by

```
$1
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/656bWF/1/).

---

For a safer way, consider using `nltk` (e.g. for `Python`) or try to get the initial source code.

Comment: That works well on regex101.com, but it's not working for NotePad++ (which uses PCRE). PCRE uses \R instead of \s, and I got it working with (.{22})\R\R* though I don't know if this is the best thing to use.

Comment: Also, I apologize for the inconsistency between the question and the answer... I modified the example a couple minutes after posting the question, and Jan grabbed my original question.